# The requested controller could not be assigned to a controller class zf2

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

Rout is define as in module.config it is going to this rout but gives an error as said above that the controller  is not assigned to any class

```
 return array(
'controllers' => array(

    'classes' => array(
    'Reisesparer\Controller\Index' => 'Reisesparer\Controller\IndexController',
    'Reisesparer\Controller\Payment' => 'Reisesparer\Controller\PaymentController',
    ),

    'invokables' => array(
        'Reisesparer\Controller\Index' => 'Reisesparer\Controller\IndexController',
        'Reisesparer\Controller\Payment' => 'Reisesparer\Controller\PaymentController',
    ),

'payment_done' => array(
   'type' => 'segment',
   'options' => array(
   'route'    => '/payment/done[/:payum_token]',
   'defaults' => array(
   '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Reisespare\Controller',
   'controller' => 'Payment',
   'action' => 'done'
       ),
     ),
   ),
```

Here the controller method:

```
namespace Reisesparer\Controller;

 use Payum\Core\Request\GetHumanStatus;
 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\Di\ServiceLocator;
 use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

 class PaymentController extends AbstractActionController
 {
    public function doneAction()
    {
    $token = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($this);

    $gateway = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('payum')->getgateway($token->getgatewayName());

    $gateway->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($token));

    return new JsonModel(array('status' => $status->getValue(), 'details' => iterator_to_array($status->getFirstModel())));
  }
}
```

Any help regarding this issue how to solve it?

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the exact error/exception?

Comment: Also I don't know what the `classes` key in your config is. https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html explains the available config keys and their function.